# VBA Range Output to Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling a bit with VBA syntax tonight, and would appreciate your help.

I have a Userform that takes input through RefEdit fields, and stores that as a variable (range). (This is done through

```
set DurationRange = range(me.refedit1.value)
```

which was an earlier question of mine tonight.

This user form takes this range input, and outputs the range into a different sheet for further processing. What I would like to do is basically output the variable again.

I'm trying that with this code:

```
with worksheets("Data Output")
    .range("a1").offset(0, counter) = "Durations" 'this line just creates a header cell
    .range("a2").offset(0, counter) = DurationsRange 'this line should output the range into cell a2
End with
```

But although this outputs the string, it does nothing for the range. What is the proper method to output a range? I know I could do a for each loop, but I have so many ranges that that seems incredibly inefficient.

Comment: what is `DurationRange` and where is the link between `CraCost`, `DurationsRange` and `Durations`?

Comment: Sorry, will edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some possible answers:

**1st.** if your `DurationRange` is a single cell range than you need to improve your code only in this line:

```
.range("a2").offset(0, counter) = DurationsRange.Value     'Value property is important here
```

**2nd.** if your `DurationRange` consists of one single column and some rows then you could possibly use this solution:

```
.range("a2").offset(0, counter).Resize(DurationRange.Rows.Count) = DurationsRange.Value     'Value property is important here, too
```

Obviously, there are some other options which could be solved in similar way to 2nd example above.